# How can I change the name property of sl-input using JavaScript?

Tags: shoelace

I have an ordinary sl-input in a form on a page

`<sl-input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email address"></sl-input>`

I want to change the `name` property of the sl-input using JavaScript.

`document.querySelector('sl-input').name = "new-email"`

The above code seems to change the `name` property of the `input` field in the **shadow DOM**, but the `sl-input`'s `name` property remains unchanged. If I then submit the form, the payload data refers to `email`, not `new-email`.

How can I change the `name` property of an `sl-input` using JavaScript?

Comment: Can you create a new component and copy all the data you need into it?

Comment: For my use case, I think I could. I still would like to know why I can't just change the name property on an existing sl-input though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name attribute can be updated using `setAttribute`.

`document.querySelector("sl-input").setAttribute("name", "new-email")`